# How to include mdc key when logging exception using Logstash encoder

Tags: java, spring, logging, logstash, spring-logback

I have `logback-spring.xml` file where I have json console appender:

I include mdc key `requestId`:

however, this requestId is lost when there is a runtime exception being logged.
is there a way I can have the requestId printed in the logs when there is an exception?

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>log_datetime</timestamp>
                <thread>thread</thread>
                <logger>[ignore]</logger>
                <version>[ignore]</version>
                <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                <callerClass>class_name</callerClass>
                <callerMethod>method_name</callerMethod>
                <callerFile>[ignore]</callerFile>
                <callerLine>line_num</callerLine>
            </fieldNames>
            <includeMdcKeyName>requestId</includeMdcKeyName>
            <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampPattern>
            <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
            <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                <maxDepthPerThrowable>30</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                <maxLength>2048</maxLength>
                <shortenedClassNameLength>20</shortenedClassNameLength>
                <exclude>sun\.reflect\..*\.invoke.*</exclude>
                <exclude>net\.sf\.cglib\.proxy\.MethodProxy\.invoke</exclude>
                <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
                <inlineHash>true</inlineHash>
            </throwableConverter>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <springProfile name="!local">
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Comment: We don't use XML configuration on our project but with Groovy configuration we log an MDC key by using `%X{keyName}`.  See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Comment: question is more about missing mdc key when there is an exception where I lose the key info

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I assume you're adding the key using ` MDC.put("keyName", "keyValue");`.  The only time we've lost the key is when a new thread is spawned and the log statement is executed in the new thread.  I don't have a good solution to that scenario, unfortunately, at least a good Spring solution.

Comment: I tried to get your issue, but unfortunality I couldn't reproduce mentioned issue with MDC fields, I used ```logstash-logback-encoder``` version 6.6, and I suppose issue is in new thread, in which exception was threw, if not so, please share code for more detaled issue review.